# How can I update the package.json using meteor add?

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, npm-install, package.json

How can I get my package.json updated by `meteor add` command as it can be achieved by `npm install --save`?

I just read [there](https://atmospherejs.com/i/installing) that meteor writes in the `.meteor/package`. Does that mean `package.json` can only be updated via `npm install --save` whereas `meteor add` only effects `.meteor/package`?

I'll highly appreciate detailed information on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of adding packages to a meteor project.

1. With meteor add
2. With npm install

These are two separate ways of managing packages, and one doesn't affect the other.

If you install, for example, jquery with `meteor add`, you'd use `import {$} 'meteor/jquery'` to use in a file.

If you use `npm install` to install jquery, then you might use `import $ from 'jquery'`.

Don't confuse npm packages with meteor packages.

Comment: Yeah there's no doubt/issue in using the packages, I think I was mixing both `meteor add` with `npm install` whereas answer is also in my question that `npm install` just effects `package.json` whereas `meteor add` effects `.meteor/package` only. As you also stated that I shouldn't mixup both of these

Comment: Yes, npm install will use the `package.json`, this is the file that configures a folder to a npm project. The meteor uses the another file, the `.meteor/package`